# OutOfBoundsException while still clearly in bounds

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been getting an `OutOfBoundsException` whenever I try to assign an element from a String array to a String variable

```
Random r = new Random();
private String[] ownerList = {"Garry, Becca, Louis, Sydney, Jermaine, Petra"};
String ownerName = ownerList[r.nextInt(5)];
```

No matter what the randomizer chooses, it is always out of bounds. I've tried hardcoding the index to
`String ownerName = ownerList[1];`
and it is still out of bounds.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You define only one entry in your array wich has index 0

Comment: Your array only contains one string, and its value is "Garry, Becca, Louis, Sydney, Jermaine, Petra"

Comment: Just to be clear, try "Gary","Becca","Louis"...

Comment: I figured it was something obvious, thanks folks!